# How to enable stand notifications on Apple Watch even in Do Not Disturb mode?

Tags: apple-watch, activity.app

When working or relaxing I like to keep my watch on Do Not Disturb, but I'd like to still get buzzed when it's time to stand. Is there a way to selectively enable a notification through DND?

Comment: I turn my phone on silent instead of DND and I get buzz notifications.  Kind of by definition Do Not Disturb shouldn't let notifications through.

Comment: Another workaround would be to put it in airplane mode. That way you would still get notifications on activity, breathing, etc. but not any from outside.

Answer (score 4):

With Focus introduced in iOS 15, you can receive Stand Reminders by adding Fitness to the allowed apps in Focus settings. Apparently the notification settings of Activity app on the Apple Watch are mirrored from settings of Fitness app on the iPhone.

This is not a perfect solution as you can receive other Activity notifications such as Goal Completions and Activity Sharing Notifications if enabled. But at least it allows you to receive Stand Reminders while muting notifications from other apps.

Answer (score 0):

After a year I finally decided to create a shortcut for this: https://www.icloud.com/shortcuts/dbb24facde0444a5a2ee0d9c724b5dd1

The loop should be customized to one's own schedule for sleeping. The prints are there to just debug the script. One should also make an automation for the beginning time f.ex. daily.

In a nutshell the shortcut disables Do Not Disturb for 10 seconds around the xx:50 phase. This allows the stand reminder to pass through notifications correctly. One could argue this is not an intuitive approach as there could be notifications passed through during that 10 seconds. Then again perhaps we should all embrace the user to manage their phone and notifications so that a push notification is not send from software x every 10 seconds or so.